# Exit program in Eiffel

Tags: eiffel

Is there a way in Eiffel to exit a program, possible with a defined exit code like `exit` in C?

In my case I would like to just end the program like `exit(0)` would do.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the default would be anything different from the `exit(0)` equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can terminate the program returning the exit code `n` with

```
{EXCEPTIONS}.die (n)
```

If you are using an older version of the compiler/libraries where the code above does not compile, the same can be achieved with

```
;(create {EXCEPTIONS}).die (n)
```